# Counter not getting resumed when an activity is resumed

Tags: android

I have a counter in my activity A and on finish of it, I have to perform some actions. The problem is the counter is getting reset when I move onto another activity and then come back to this activity A, which shouldn't happen. Why is it so?

My Counter class is:

```
private class Counter extends CountDownTimer {

        public Counter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            //perform some actions
        }

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int minute = (int) (millisUntilFinished / (1000 * 60));
            int sec = (int) ((millisUntilFinished - (minute * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);
            minuteText.setText("" + minute);
            secondText.setText("" + sec);
            }
        }
    }
```

I call my counter in `onCreate()` as:

```
new Counter(countdowntime * 60 * 1000), 1000).start();
```

How to solve this issue? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no experience with this class. If you are saving the state of the timer in two EditText Views. Using standard techniques, the state of these fields should persist, even on orientation change, so that you should be able to re-initialize the counter in ?onCreate using the state saved in these views. A cleaner solution may be to write the time remaining to a bundle in onSaveInstanceState and read the bundle in onCreate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked...The problem was i was using activity stack...while calling an intent we should give an id for it so that it uniquely identifies each intent. When I gave that, it got worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably start your counter in `onResume` instead of in `onCreate` and pause the counter in `onPause` (or you could finish the counter if `isFinishing()` returns `true` in `onPause`).